# how to display connection error when link is clicked from a cached page in UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I'm working on an app with a `UIWebView` that goes to a single page -- we'll call it `http://myPage.com` -- that has a few links on it.  Displaying a `UIAlertView` for a connection error when the user first clicks the go-to-myPage button that leads to `http://myPage.com` is no problem.  But if there's no connection and the user clicks the go-to-myPage button, gets no `UIAlertView` because the cached version of `http://myPage.com` is returned, and then tries to follow a link from `http://myPage.com`, nothing happens.  How can I rewrite or add to my code to display an alert in such a situation?

Here's my code:

```
-(void)loadWebViewWithbaseURLString:bus withURLString:us
{
self.request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:us] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval: 20];
self.connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.request delegate:nil];
NSError *error=nil;
NSURLResponse *response=nil;
if (self.connection)
{
    self.urlData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: self.request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self.webV loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:bus]];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    alert.title = @"Unfortunately, I seem to be having a hard time connecting to the Internet.  Would you mind trying again later?  I'll make it worth your while, I promise.";
    [alert show];
}
}
```

And of course the go-to-myPage code simply calls `-(void)loadWebViewWithbaseURLString:bus withURLString:us` with the specific URLs as arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question in a clearer (I hope) way at [NSURLRequest cachePolicy and connection in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102017/nsurlrequest-cachepolicy-and-connection-in-uiwebview) and was ultimately able to figure it out myself, so I posted the answer....