# NSURLRequest cachePolicy and connection in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.4

I set up a UIWebView with a cachePolicy of NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, and everything was fine:  when there was a connection, the UIWebView loaded, and when there wasn't, connection:didFailWithError: was called and I got my UIAlertView.

But when I change the cachePolicy to NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad (which is the policy I actually want), in the absence of a connection, the cached page loads and then, when I click on a link...nothing happens.  No connection:didFailWithError: called.  No UIAlertView.

How do I fix this?

**EDIT:**  Perhaps I have the *beginning* of an answer....  I can at least identify when a link in the UIWebView is clicked, using the following method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)req navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        NSLog(@"Blah!");
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Now, instead of NSLogging "Blah!" I just need to get it to call connection:didFailWithError.

So how do I do *that*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it!

I added this code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)req navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        NSURL *scriptUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.homePageOfTheApp.com"];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:scriptUrl];
        if (data == nil)
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error title." message:@"Error message." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
return YES;
```

}

Though I might replace `http://www.homePageOfTheApp.com"` with `http://www.google.com` since, even though my host has very reliable servers, I'm going to guess that Google's are even better....